# Why can't I call random number from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem calling random number from the database.
Here is the my link:

```
<form method="post" action="pages/test.php?id=<?php echo "$id[0]";?>&ran=<?php echo "$ran";?>">
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Click here" class="button"> 
</form>
```

And here is my second page code:

```
<?php

if (!isset($submit)) {

//database connection here

$id = $_GET['id']; 
$ran = $_GET['ran']; 
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id' AND ran='$ran'";

$result2 = mysql_query ($query2) or die ('Could not run query: ' .   mysql_error());

$info = mysql_fetch_array ($result2);

?>
```

When I call for example firstname or lastname it woks okay. But $ran is returning empty. Am I missing something.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. For starters you're making a `$_POST` submission, but you have `$_GET` requests in your second page.

Comment: You shouldn't wrap your `$id[0]` in double quotes. ie `<?php echo $id[0];?>`

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don't totally understand your request, one notable error I can see is below.

Your second page should be like this

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) {

//database connection here

$id = $_POST['id']; 
$ran = $_POST['ran']; 
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id' AND ran='$ran'";

$result2 = mysql_query ($query2) or die ('Could not run query: ' .   mysql_error());

$info = mysql_fetch_array ($result2);

}

?>
```